# Como puedo limitar lo que esta dentro de un div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Buenas compañeros tengo un problema con los divs con bootstra no puedo hacer que con carousel de bootstrap se adapte al div , este es una maquetacion que hice para que mas o menos quisiera tener el carusel dentro del el div rojo y azul adaptarlos a esos tamaños , si me podrian ayudar se los agradeceria mucho

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
#sistema_de_turno{
     position: absolute;
     float: left;
     width:20%;
        height: 90%; 

       
         margin: 10px;
       background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    }
      
    #videos{
        margin-top: 14.5%;
     width:75%;

        height: 60%; 
        margin-left: 21%;
       position: absolute;
    }

    #banner{
       
     width:75%;
  height: 30%; 
 
  
   margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 21%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;


    }
          #videos video{
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 80%;
    }
    #oficina{
     height: 90%;
     width: 50%;  
     
         margin: 0px;
        
          float: left;
    }#turno{
     height: 90%;
     float: left;
     width: 50%;  
    
          margin: 0px;
          
  
    }
    #oficinas{
        margin:0;
        height: 18%;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    #turno-sisben{
        height: 18%;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
      #turno-familia{
        height: 18%;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
      }
      #turno-salud{
        height: 18%;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
      }
      #turno-despacho{
        height: 18%;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
      }
      #turno-adulto{
        height: 18%;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
      }
    #turno-sisben h1{
     margin-top: 10px;
       
            text-align-last: center;
            color:white;
            display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:normal;
    }
      #turno-sisben h1{
        margin-top: 10px;
          
            text-align-last: center;
            color:white;
            display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:normal;
      }
      #turno-sisben h1{
        margin-top: 10px;
          
            text-align-last: center;
            color:white;
            display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:normal;
      }
      #turno-familia h1{
        margin-top: 10px;
          
            text-align-last: center;
            color:white;
            display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:normal;
      }
      #turno-salud h1{
        margin-top: 10px;
          
            text-align-last: center;
            color:white;
            display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:normal;
      }
      #turno-despacho h1{
        margin-top: 10px;
          
            text-align-last: center;
            color:white;
            display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:normal;
      }#turno-adulto h1{
        margin-top: 10px;
          
            text-align-last: center;
            color:white;
            display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:normal;
      }#oficinas p{
            text-align-last: center;
            color:white;
            

            
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TURNO</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/divs.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body>


    <div  id="sistema_de_turno" >
    
   <div id="oficina"><h5>OFICINA</h5>

    <div id="oficinas"><p align="center">SISBEN</p></div>
    <div id="oficinas"><p align="center">FAMILIAS </p></div>
    <div id="oficinas"><p align="center">SALUD</p></div>
    <div id="oficinas"><p align="center">DESPACHO</p></div>
    <div id="oficinas"><p align="center">ADULTO MAYOR</p></div>
  
    </div>
    <div id="turno">
      <h5>TURNOS</h5>
     <div id="turno-sisben" data-toggle="counter-up"><h1>00</h1></div>
     <div id="turno-familia" data-toggle="counter-up"><h1>00</h1></div>
     <div id="turno-salud" data-toggle="counter-up"><h1>00</h1></div>
     <div id="turno-despacho" data-toggle="counter-up"><h1>00</h1></div>
     <div id="turno-adulto" data-toggle="counter-up"><h1>00</h1></div>
    </div>
     
      </div>
    
      
  
      <div id="banner" class="bg-danger"></div>
      <div id="videos" class="bg-primary">
        
      </div>

 
</div>
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes adjuntar una imagen de como quieres que se ajuste al tamaño de los otros dos bloques de color? y otra cosa: ¿Porque usaste posiciones absolutas? si estas maquetando con bootstrap? A parte quieres copiar el ancho y alto de los otros div? pero sin que el carrusel este dentro de estos? Entendí bien?

Comment: Quiero que el div donde coloque el carousel se adapte a donde lo coloque digamos en el de banner se adapte el carousel al tamaño del banner igual que las imagenes

Comment: Cuesta mucho entenderte, quizás sea yo sólo, pero por lo general si no has recibido respuesta en este tiempo, es porque no queda claro que quieres lograr.

Comment: que el carousel se adapte al div o quede de esa manera como lo estoy planteando en la maquetacion

Comment: Esto fue lo que hice espero que te sirva
https://codepen.io/ramon-albares/pen/bjyyqM